# Unable to install

Tags: installation

I am a beginner in Android who has got miserably stuck up with the following message in Android Studio:

‘Launching 'app' on Xiaomi Redmi Y2.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.
Installation failed due to: 'null'’
I had already tried: adding -r-t in install flag in run configuration, clean, rebuild, invalidate caches etc.   all of no avail. Finally I uninstalled the studio and reinstalled the same..But when I added a device, again the error message repeats! Experts, please rescue me!

Answer (score 0):

Silly of me,  I had forgotten to reboot the phone!  Once I did that the problem is solved.